# Cannot Set @api Property For LWC Component In Lightning Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have a LWC component, that has a very simple public property:

```
@api recordId;
```

And I have a LWC config, that exposes this public property to the Flow Builder

```
<targets>
<target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
        <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record Id" default="{!recordId}" required="true"></property>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

In my flow, there is a standard variable recordId, and when I put my LWC in one of these screen actions, I can even select the "Record Id" and fill it with `{!recordId}`. But: `recordId` (in the LWC) never gets populated. It is populated in the Flow. At least it seems that way, if I output {!recordId} in a "display text"

Why?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar scenario where I wasn't able to the record Id passed into my component in a flow, but it worked on a record page. I tried using the result of a query {!getOpportunity.Id} rather than {!recordId} even though they would be identical and that worked. Perhaps the reason has something to do with this:

> The recordId is set only when you place or invoke the component in an
> explicit record context. In all other cases, the recordId isn’t set,
> and your component shouldn’t depend on it.

From Developer.Salesforce.com: [Make a Component Aware of Its Record Context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context)

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that default values did not work at all for design properties in the LWC Flow but it would work in a community.

I have an example here: [Pass record ID to custom LWC Component and Modal Flow Screen](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319986/pass-record-id-to-custom-lwc-component-and-modal-flow-screen/320776#320776)

This wasn't only for recordId but when I would try to pass a hardcoded string Object as well as default for example 'MyObject__share'

**This works:**

```
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
        <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record Id" description="Input Record Id as a string or use variable {!recordId}"/>
        <property name="shareObject" label="Share Object API Name" description="Type in Share Object API Name ex: MyObject__share" type="String"/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

**This did not:**

```
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
        <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record Id" description="Input Record Id as a string or use variable {!recordId}"/>
        <property name="shareObject" label="Share Object API Name" description="Type in Share Object API Name ex: Serious_Incident__share" type="String" default="myObject__share"/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```